# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler

Tags: jsf

I'm working on a web project with Hibernate, Spring and JSF. When I run the project, I get the following exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler(Application.java:286)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Show some code first. This exception is generated by almost every second error:-)

Comment: Please translate the error message!

Comment: this is the whole message written in the console..
there is just this error message

Comment: I fixed your question, but please change your environment from French to English so that you get English error messages. You'll find *so many more* positive hits when you search an error message in English on Stack Overflow and Google.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is caused because the JSF implementation suitable to the JSF API is absent in the runtime classpath. The solution is to put the JSF implementation JAR file in the runtime classpath.

In other words, you have a `/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-api.jar` file, but not a `/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl.jar` file, at least not of the same version as the JSF API JAR file. You need to make sure that you supply one, at least of the proper version.