# WebLogic Server : BEA-101020 Servlet failed with an Exception

Tags: exception, weblogic

I'm new to WebLogic server and I'm trying to run WLS application with IntelliJ. The app runs well, then I log in through the log in screen of my web app, but after that I get an error in the console :

```
   <15 avr. 2021 11 h 47 CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1146411793[app:my-app-ear_ear_exploded module:/my-app path:null spec-version:4.0]] Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler(Application.java:287)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:588)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
```

I have already searched on Google and could not find an answer (the Oracle documentation says that BEA-101020 error code states that an error occured and that we should read logs, but logs are not very explicit). Maybe it has something to do with the `path: null`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: looks like you have version mismatch or exact https://stackoverflow.com/a/14845904/175554, check your lib versions and weblogic libs are aligned.

Comment: My project is currently using 1.2_14 version for both jsf-api and jsp-impl in pom.xml so there is no mismatch between these versions

Comment: did you try prefer-web-inf-classes https://stackoverflow.com/a/48316878/175554 weblogic brings its own implementation that may break you app.